# Toggle button color by calling function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm new to vb.net. I have 20 buttons in one form. When I click any of one button, it color should be changed.

I can code for all button like following. But I need a function, when i call that function, the color should be changed. Please help me and give me full coding

```
 Private Sub btnR1X1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnR1X1.Click
    If (btnR1X1.BackColor = Color.White) Then
        btnR1X1.BackColor = Color.Gray
    ElseIf (btnR1X1.BackColor = Color.Gray) Then
        btnR1X1.BackColor = Color.White
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: First, you need to understand vb6 ≠ vb.net

Comment: Subclass the button.

Comment: Sorry for that, Could you please help me to do that subclass?

Comment: Do you want the color to reverse everytime? That is, if it's white, it will be grey and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that you are using VB.Net. Assuming that is the case, you should edit your question to remove the vb6 tag.

You can write a function that will toggle the BackColor of any control.

```
Private Sub ToggleColor(ctrl As Control)
    If ctrl.BackColor = Color.White Then ctrl.BackColor = Color.Gray Else ctrl.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

You can call that function from a Button's click handler like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ToggleColor(CType(sender, Control))
End Sub
```

However, if all you want to do when any of the buttons is clicked is to toggle the BackColor, you can use a single event handler for the click event of every button.

```
Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click 'etc
    Dim ctrl as Control = CType(sender, Control)
    If ctrl.BackColor = Color.White Then ctrl.BackColor = Color.Gray Else ctrl.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```